# cfn-signal in aws cloudformation with launchConfiguration and AutoScalingGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following configuration in my AWS Cloudformation template.

The template creates one EC2 instance based on `instance1`. I am using the reference to same instance in my LaunchConfiguration to create the instances of same type. 
The problem I am facing is by including the CreationPolicy element in my AutoScalingGroup template. I get the following error when ASG launches an instance and waits for the cfn-signal.

```
+ /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 --stack ss07 --resource Instance1 --region us-west-2
ValidationError: Resource Instance1 is in CREATE_COMPLETE state and cannot be signaled
```

It seems like somehow the reference is made to an already existing instance1 and not to the instance being created by LaunchConfig. I saw examples which had the LaunchConfig embedded within, but I want to keep the instance details at one place instead of two places.

```
"instance1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "configSets": {
            "install": ["yum_packages","install_cfn"]
          },

          "yum_packages": {
              "packages" : {
                  "yum" : {
                    "awslogs"        : [],
                    "ruby"        : [],
                    "wget"        : [],
                    "httpd"       : []
                  }
            }
          },
          "install_cfn": {
            "files": {
              "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "[main]\n",
                      "stack=",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                      },
                      "\n",
                      "region=",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "mode": "000400",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root"
              },
              "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                      "triggers=post.update\n",
                      "path=Resources.WebServer.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                      "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                      "         --stack ",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      },
                      "         --resource splitsweetInstance ",
                      "         --configsets install ",
                      "         --region ",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "mode": "000400",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root"
              }             
            },
            "services": {
              "sysvinit": {
                "cfn-hup": { "enabled": "true",  "ensureRunning": "true",  "files": [
                    "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf",
                    "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"
                                ]
                            }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "CreationPolicy": {
        "ResourceSignal": {
          "Timeout": "PT10M"
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": {
                "Fn::FindInMap": [
                    "AWSRegionArch2AMI", {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    }, {
                        "Fn::FindInMap": [
                            "AWSInstanceType2Arch", {
                                "Ref": "instanceType1"
                            },
                            "Arch"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
        "InstanceType": {"Ref": "instanceType1"},
        "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName"},
        "Monitoring": "false",
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
             "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
             "yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

             "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource splitsweetInstance ",
             "         --configsets install ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

             "wget ", { "Fn::FindInMap": [  "Region2CodeDeployAgent", { "Ref": "AWS::Region"},  "url"] }, "\n",
             "chmod +x ./install\n",
             "./install auto\n",

             "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource splitsweetInstance ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"

        ]]}},
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "inst1"
          }
        ],
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
            { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "instance1Sg", "GroupId" ] }
        ]
      }
    }
```

My Launch Config is as follows -

```
"LaunchConfig1": {
       "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
       "Properties" : {
          "ImageId": {
            "Fn::FindInMap": [
                "AWSRegionArch2AMI", {
                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                }, {
                    "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "AWSInstanceType2Arch", {
                            "Ref": "instanceType1"
                        },
                        "Arch"
                    ]
                }
            ]
          },
          "InstanceId" : { "Ref":"instance1"},
          "InstanceMonitoring" : "false",
          "InstanceType" : { "Ref": "instanceType1"},
          "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
          "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "instance1Sg", "GroupId" ] } ]
       }
    }
```

This is my AutoScalingGroup template -

```
    "AutoScalingGroup1":    {
       "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
       "Properties" : {
          "AvailabilityZones" :  {  "Fn::GetAZs": { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }   },
          "Cooldown" : "60",
          ....
          "LaunchConfigurationName" : {"Ref":"LaunchConfig1"},
          "MaxSize" : "3",
          "MinSize" : "1",
          "TargetGroupARNs" : [ {"Ref":"TargetGroup1"} ],
          "VPCZoneIdentifier" : [   { "Ref": "subnetCache1" },   { "Ref": "subnetCache2" },  { "Ref": "subnetCache3" }  ]
       },
       "CreationPolicy" : {
        "ResourceSignal" : {
          "Timeout" : "PT6M",
          "Count"   : "1"
         }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that by specifying the [`InstanceId`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-instanceid) property in your [`LaunchConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) resource, it is reusing the same UserData that was used to launch the initial EC2 instance, including the hard-coded reference to the Logical Resource signaled by the `cfn-signal` command. According to the documentation,

> When you use an instance to create a launch configuration, all properties are derived from the instance with the exception of `BlockDeviceMapping` and `AssociatePublicIpAddress`. You can override any properties from the instance by specifying them in the launch configuration.

To have `cfn-signal` signal the correct Resource, you will need to override the [`UserData`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-userdata) in your `LaunchConfiguration` resource to contain a User-Data script that references the Launch Configuration rather than the original EC2 instance. Unfortunately, this will require either duplicating the User-Data script, or rewriting the script to dynamically figure out the Logical Resource associated with the instance the script is currently running on, so the same exact User-Data can be used in both the original EC2 instance and the auto scaling group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. additional questions on your answer - 1. Would the metadata be still applied if I override the UserData? I could not find a specify the metadata in the LaunchConfiguration. 2. Regarding your second comment, is there an example to dynamically figure out the logical resource association?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with wjordan that part of the problem you are having is with the `InstanceId` property in `LaunchConfiguration`. Also looking at your code sample I could not figure out where `splitsweetInstance` was referenced.

However my CloudFormation `AutoScalingGroup` was not set up this way and I still got the same error `CREATE_COMPLETE state and cannot be signaled`.

The solution for me was setting the `DesiredCapacity` on the `AutoScalingGroup` (hopefully this helps others as well) was found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-desiredcapacity

As per the docs:

> CloudFormation will not mark the Auto Scaling group as successful (by setting its status to CREATE_COMPLETE) until the desired capacity is reached.

This is what that portion of my CloudFormation template looks like:

```
"WebServerGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref" : "Subnets" },
    "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
    "MinSize" : "2",
    "MaxSize" : "4",
    "DesiredCapacity" : "2",
    "TargetGroupARNs" : [ { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" } ]
  }
```

Below is the "signal" portion of UserData section:

```
         "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
         "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
         "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
         "         --resource WebServerGroup ",
         "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I ensured that I added both ***CreationPolicy*** & ***UpdatePolicy*** in Autoscaling group before using ***cfn-signal*** in ***UserData*** section of the LaunchTemplate

```
    CreationPolicy:
      AutoScalingCreationPolicy:
        MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent: somepercent
      ResourceSignal:
      Count: somenumber
      Timeout: someminutes
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingScheduledAction:
        IgnoreUnmodifiedGroupSizeProperties: 'true'
    AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
      MinInstancesInService: 'somenumber'
      MaxBatchSize: 'somenumber'
      PauseTime: someminutes
      WaitOnResourceSignals: 'true'
```